# Vue define where is the index.html file

Tags: node.js, vue.js

I am very new to Vue and node and I am trying to insert a global value in my project but to do so I want to put my `index.html` in a public dir.
I first create a project, but the public src was not created, and I can run it with:

```
$ npm run dev
```

If I create the public dir and put the `index.html` into it, I got an fatal error (without any other message) when I run `$ npm run dev`.
So I installed `@vue/cli-service` with node, by `$ npm install --save @vue/cli-service` but nothing change, I have also try to find `vue.config.js`, that is mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52684709/vue-index-html-favicon-issue) question, but I didn't find it.

(In my package.json there is this dependecies:
`"@vue/cli-service": "^3.0.0",`)

What am I doing wrong?
Thank you

PS: What I am trying to do is to use [this](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html#Automatic-Global-Registration-of-Base-Components) and add BAse_URL in my index File, but before that, If I put `index.html` in the public dir I got the error

Comment: Did you create the project via **vue create my-project** ?

Comment: I create it with vue init webpack projectname

Comment: What do you mean by *trying to insert a global value* ? Is it a global js file, string etc?

Comment: whats wring with these methods?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49314142/read-configuration-globally-in-vue-js-like-mixins

Comment: I add the link in the post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Vue-CLI 3 and 4 (and up) no index.html is created in the src folder.
So if you want to include any file to your project (such as a CSS file or Jquery Library), you can simply import that in App.vue:

```
import './assets/css/yourstyles.css';
```

or in one of the styles globally (for CSS files):

```
<style>
@import './assets/styles/yourstyles.css';
</style>
```